# Twilio how to add a PAUSE within a switch statement

Tags: node.js, twilio

I have five menus that a user can choose from when they dial a number from their phone. Each menu has 4 to 6 options. Using the .say in Twilio all options are spoken very fast and I would like to slow that down. A comma after each sentence does not slow it down enough so I have been trying to use .pause without any luck. My thought was to use use 4 to 6 .say within a case and a .pause for 2 seconds between each .say

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

I have tried

```
// Test Menu      
     case '6':
     twiml.gather({numDigits: 1})
     .say('I will pause 5 seconds starting now!')
     .pause(5)
     .say('Now for the second sentence.');
    twiml.redirect('');
      break;
```

but I get the following error in my debugging

Error - 82002
Error on Twilio Function response

Your Function invocation resulted in StatusCode 5xx.
Possible Causes

```
Your Function timed out before responding
Your Function returned an error response
```

Possible Solutions

```
Your Function must contain a callback.
Make sure you place the Function callback callback(err, response) is placed correctly in your Function code.
If you are using a JavaScript promise, make sure the callback is called in both success and catch blocks.
Your Function responded with an error.
```

```
{
    "message": "twiml.gather(...).say(...).pause is not a function",
    "name": "TypeError",
    "stack": "TypeError: twiml.gather(...).say(...).pause is not a function\n    at Object.exports.handler (/var/task/handlers/ZF38fa6cf6d9f5d40cd5983794f7f70df3.js:57:7)\n    at Object.exports.handler (/var/task/node_modules/enigma-lambda/index.js:306:10)\n    at exports.handler (/var/task/enigma.js:17:9)"
}
```

The following code works as is, but plays the options to fast in each case. I am trying to use .say and .pause in the Test Menu (Case 6) but have been unsuccessful in every idea I have tried.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) 
{
  let finishOnKey = '0';
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  switch (event.Digits) 
  {
// Case 1       
case '1':
      twiml.gather({numDigits: 1})
      .say(‘Message.');
      twiml.redirect('');
      break;

// Case 2     
 case '2':
      twiml.gather({numDigits: 1})
      .say(‘Message.');
      twiml.redirect('');
      break;

//Case 3      
case '3':
      twiml.gather({numDigits: 1})
      .say('Message.');
      twiml.redirect('');
      break;


//Case 4      
case '4':
      twiml.gather({numDigits: 1})
      .say('Message. ');
      twiml.redirect('');
      break;


//Case 5   
  case '5':
      twiml.gather({numDigits: 1})
      .say('Message.');
      twiml.redirect('');
      break;

// Test Menu      
     case '6':
     twiml.gather({numDigits: 1})
     .say('I will pause 5 seconds starting now!')
     .pause(5);
     .say('Now for the second sentence.');
    twiml.redirect('');
      break;

// Pressing * repeats the current menu
     case '*':
      twiml.gather({numDigits: 1,action:'/XXX_General_Info'})
      .say(‘Message.');
      break;

// Main menu
    default:
        twiml.gather({numDigits: 1,action:'/XXX'})
        .say('Message. To repeat these options press star. To go back 
        to the main menu press zero. To end this call just hang up, 
        or press pound.');
  }
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Comment: The say verb supports Amazon Polly, which includes a way to set in the voice speed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/voice-speed-vip.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to use Polly's Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML), as Devin suggested. Make sure your Twilio Function Twilio helper library is up to date (under Configure). If it says 3.6.3, you are using an older library and must enter a newer version. The latest version of the Twilio Node helper library can be found [HERE][1], (3.36.0 as of today).

Example Twilio Function Node.js code to get you started in the right direction is below. Have Fun!

```
    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    let gather = twiml.gather({numDigits: 1});
    gather.say({voice: 'Polly.Joanna'}, 'Hi')
        .ssmlBreak({strength: 'x-weak',time: '2000ms'});
        gather.say({voice: 'Polly.Joanna'}, 'How are you?');
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Comment: The following code works great for putting a pause between the two sentences, but it does not seem to work in a switch statement because when I press a key, twilio does not detect it.

Comment: Changed the code a bit. You just have to work with the code, to make sure the Say is nested within the Gather.